# Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getViewModelStore for spy(fragment) object

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

[image]

did anyone else faced the similar problem, details are:
in earlier version of  androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1  library the mockito based tests passes but after upgrading the library to 1.5.3 version the tests fails by giving this error.

code which is used to test the fragment:

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(AppCompatActivity::class.java).setup().get()
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit()
if (idleLooper) {
    shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle()
}
```

here If I pass the normal fragment object, the tests runs and it continue to run the test, but if I pass spy(fragment) and then try to run code (test) it breaks with the above error.

gone through the change documentation for library as well, but nothing specific is mentioned regarding fragmentmanager.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.5.4
[release version documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.5.4)

I tried:

- passing the fragment object which does pass the test cases, but spy(fragment) gives error in the 1.5.3 version of library, and same code passes till 1.4.3 library.
- tried fragementScenario bases test case but that also fails to load the fragment and same error appears while running tests.
- I'm having error in the tests only (Roboelectric & mockito based tests)
- here is the fragement object I'm passing
  MyFragment(contact, viewmodel, fragmentManger)
  and the viewmodel and fragement are mock objects, and contact is just data object)

Comment: Did you find any possible solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well. You can fix by using the `Mockito.spy(Class<T>)` overload instead of constructing the fragment and using `Mockito.spy(Object)`.

For example, assuming mockito-kotlin:

```
val fragment = spy<MyFragment>()
// instead of:
val fragment = spy(MyFragment())
```

More details:

The relevant change from `androidx:fragment` is this: https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/b651a62816e8005a0e1c7fbd3435c01820f4c015

If you insantiate the fragment first, `Fragment` now constructs a `LifecycleRegistry` with reference to itself. Then when you `spy()` the instance, Mockito constructs another (mocked) instance with its own lifecycle. This causes problems when attaching the spied fragment.

By using `spy(Class<T>)`, only one instance of the fragment is created.